# Change the Product List Widget from Slider to Flat Display on Magento 2

Tags: magento2

My magento 2 is using free theme Bizkick from HiddenTechies. On the front-page the product list (Featured product, New Products etc) are listed as a slider. As diagram.
[image]

is that possible in Magento to change by simple configuration that replaces the slider by a flat display so the product selected by this widget are shown as columns and rows ( without the slider )?